# Why is this question not re-opened and what work is needed to make it re-openable?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

I have tried to edit this question (closed by one **moderator** vote):

[What does a company typically expect from a Perl developer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/108992/what-does-a-company-expects-from-a-perl-developer)

to be as clear as possible and most importantly to be objective AND to address specific concerns raised by the moderator in comments.

However, the question remains unopened despite my flagging it for moderator re-review, with no moderator feedback.

So, my meta question is:

- What specifically is the deficiency in the **updated** wording of the question which makes it not satisfy "six guidelines for constructive subjective questions"?

or, alternately:

- What possible areas of fixing are suggested?

Thanks in advance.

Please note that empirically, it's very hard to claim that the question as worded can not be answered not-too-poorly, since it DOES have an answer (disclaimer: mine) upvoted 4 times despite pretty narrow target audience (it's limited to Perl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason I closed the question is the following statement - which is still in the question:

> I know the question may be off topic because each company has its own requirements.

That is the nub of the issue. Each company will have it's own requirements so any answer will be either a) guesswork or b) the answerer's own requirements which won't help you in this particular case.

Each answer will be equally wrong and hence equally valid.

The other closing choice would have been "too localised" for much the same reasons.

Comment: Thanks for answerng. Did you see my response? Could you please clarify how my response is either too localized OR company specific OR guesswork?

Comment: @DVK - I don't remember seeing the response, but the line about each company having it's own requirements is still in the question.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't bother editing it out since I thought my answer was 100% clearly showing why that statement was wrong, but it definitely doesn't add anything to the question so I edited it out completely. Please see if it passes muster now (and please render an opinion on whether my answer specifically addresses your concern about not being able to provide an objective generic answer).

Comment: Basically, my main concern is that this is a VERY valid question that ANY junior Perl programmer has at some point or another. I know I had. So I'd prefer to work on addressing the wording's shortcomings rather than give up.

Comment: @DVK - I've reopened the question.